# How to set a class attribute in TypeScript as a Moment type?

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, angular-moment, angular2-moment

I'm able to use moment.JS and all of the methods, but I want to set an attribute in my class to be a type `Moment`, similar to a type `string` or a type `boolean`.

Eg,

```
export class Event {
  checkin_datetime: Moment;
}
```

However, I'm getting a TypeScript error of "cannot find name 'Moment'". I am able to use all `moment` methods, except for this. Another words `moment()` works but I can't assign a `Moment`.

I'm doing `import * as moment from 'moment';` on the top of my class.

Answer (score 0):

`import { Moment } from 'moment';` seemed to work. This was trivial but none of the other threads had this. Hope this helped somebody.